# Should a cipher whose answer is in the English language be tagged [english]

Tags: discussion

It seems really obvious because the assumption is likely to be that, if a question is written in English and it is a cipher, that the result of that cipher will be in English. Obviously there can be situations where a special puzzle will not be maybe but basically, is it worth tagging a cipher written in English with the English tag? Is it helpful at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. On PSE (and the SE network in general, barring language specific sites), content is assumed to be in English, so specifying as much is redundant and unhelpful.

The [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) tag is used for puzzles that rely specifically on some quirk/feature of the *English language itself* in order to function, not just for puzzles that happen to be written in English. So you might tag your theoretical cipher [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) (and/or [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)) if, for example, its encryption was autokeyed somehow to rely on the position (or not) of the letter `U` in US/UK variant spellings (`colo[u]r`) of each prior word*.

<sub>* This would make for a terrible puzzle, but I'm struggling to come up with a good example on the spot...</sub>